# SharePoint CU update installation order in Server Farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, sharepoint-farm

There is a SharePoint 2013 Farm where a SharePoint Cummulative Update (CU) / Uber Package needs to be installed. The SharePoint Farm consists of the following 3 servers:

1 Web Front End Server

1 Application Server

1 SQL Server.

As I understand, the CU (Uber Package) needs to be installed on the WFE server and on the APP server. The SQL Server SharePoint databases will be updated by running the SharePoint Products and Configuration Wizard. The CU does not need to run on the SQL Server.

In order to save time, is it possible to install the CU (Uber Package) on the Web Front End Server and on the Application Server at the same time, or should I install it seperatly on each server (first WFE, second APP)?

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,

Comment: Start with the server containing Central Admin (probably the app-server) then install on WFE, after that run psconfig. That is the preferred way

Comment: @RobertLindgren: That's the way I've always done it. But is is possible & safe to install the CU Binaries (the update) on both the APP and WFE simoltaneously? This in order to save time.

Comment: You should be able to install the binaries simultaniously I guess, but you should not run psconfig simultaneously.

Comment: @RobertLindgren: So after installing the binaries simultaneously, i run the PSConfig one at a time on both servers , starting with the Central Administration server (APP Server) and next the Web Server. The PsConfig needs to be run on both servers (one at a time)?

Comment: @TempaC You can install the CU at the same time, but can only run PsConfig at one server at the time.

Comment: Correct @TempaC

Comment: And you won't be able to run psconfig until the binaries have been installed on all servers in the farm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can install the binaries on both server at same time.

- Installation of binaries can be parallel
- But SharePoint product and configuration wizard is single thread, which means 1 server at a time. Start with Central admin server.

Couple of things you have to consider before applying the CU.

- Do the updates on off hours or a schedule activity as it will cause outage for the end users while farm is being upgraded.
- Take the full backup of your database before start of the update, In case of disaster or CU failed then  you cannot uninstall the CU. Rather you have to build the farm or fix the issues with help of MSFT.
- Test your CU in lower farm 1st, this is help to avoiding tons of issues in production.

Comment: The installation of the binaries together with the reboot can be done in parallel. In my case the installation of updates was done after hours. Thank you all for your help.